# Convert string expression into JS object (not JSON)

Tags: javascript, object

I have an expression like this inside a contenteditable div:

```
{
    name : "Jeff",
    job : "rat whacker"
}
```

How can I get this into a JS object?

If I grab the string from the div:

```
$("div").text();
```

...I get this:

```
"{\n    name: \"Jeff\",\n    job: \"rat whacker\"\n}"
```

Obviously JSON.parse won't work since this isn't valid JSON. How can I grab this as text but then assign it to a regular JSON object:

```
{
    name : "Jeff",
    job : "rat whacker"
}
```

Comment: `eval` and `new Function` are the ways to evaluate text as JavaScript code (if that's what you actually want).

Comment: As you said, it's not JSON. You have to either fix things so that it **is** valid JSON, or else come up with your own parsing scheme.

Comment: If it is an editable div, then better explain to the users that edit it that they should enter JSON only.

Comment: but note that `eval` and `new Function` (and `setTimeout`/`setInterval` with string content) are almost universally locked down and not allowed (unless you go out of your way to allow them) on modern server setups because they are _incredibly_ dangerous and make XSS attacks trivial. So the real solution is to take the text content from your div, and convert it either convert it to JSON and then parse it, or literally just build a JS object directly based on the string by using a JS grammar tokenizer (no idea if there is on, for simple objects like this, you could just write one yourself)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought new Function was the safer alternative to eval?

Comment: Sure, but "safer" does not mean "safe": there is no "safe alternative", all four allow arbitrary code execution, with access to `globalThis`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sites like CodePen must use them then, although they also likely leverage sandboxed iframes

Comment: Not "likely", they _absolutely_ use sandboxed iframes, that even run content via a different domain (cdpn.io) so that even if someone runs intentionally malicious code, it can't access any storage associated with codepen.io itself.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the last thing you want to do is trust people. Someone *is* going to abuse your site if you allow arbitrary code execution, so make that impossible: write code that validates user input before it's allowed to even make it to the next step.

Either take the textContent from your div, rewrite it so that it's valid JSON, and then parse that JSON (bonus: `JSON.parse` automatically throws an error if the input can't be parsed, so you can write a pretty simply string replacement that works for the kind of input you want, while yielding bad JSON for anything else, and the `JSON.parse` function will just reject bad input), or literally parse the text string as JS, using a JS parser that is set to throw away any active content (`function`, fat arrow notation, exercution operators, etc). If you only want to allow simple input like what you're showing, then writing your own simple-and-limited-JS parser is a little bit of work, but might be more than enough.